# Get link address from div and redirect to it using javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

Here's the code:

```
<div class="thank_you">
   <p>
     <strong>Title</strong> – <a href="product-link">Product Link</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a time delayed re-direct to a product link (links to pay-per-view content).  I'm guessing the download link would need to be grabbed after the page has loaded as the link is provided dynamically.

Comment: Do you want to extract the product-link from the div then redirect the page to it?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect the page to the link 'product-link'

Comment: Kiyura, I don't know any javascript, so I've tried Googling the solution... no luck

Comment: @Kiyura tried zshooter's solution `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {setTimeout('delayer()', 5000);});function delayer(){window.location = $('.thank_you p a').attr('href');}</script>` but no luck, any advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php) page has what you want:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = document.getElementById('myElement').getAttribute('href');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: So this:    `function delayer(){
    window.location = $('.thank_you p a').attr('href');
}

<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">` is right?

Comment: you need to add the function to a script tag, but that should get it done

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, here's what I have: `<script type="text/javascript">

function delayer(){ window.location = $('.thank_you p a').attr('href'); } <body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">

</script>`

Comment: the `body` tag should replace your `<body>` not go in the script

Comment: ahh I see. This is in a Wordpress installation, script is inserted into a page. How can I add `onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)"` to the body tag for this page?

Comment: changed to a javascript only implementation.  I should not that this is using JQuery, so it has to be included on your page (it can be done without it if you prefer to convert it to not use JQuery).

Comment: no joy. Using jQuery 1.7 if that helps...

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing (errors in console?)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: odd... it's called in the header `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>` You mentioned it can be done without jQuery?

Comment: error console says delayer(anonymous function) if that helps

Comment: try `function delayer(){ window.location = jQuery('.thank_you p a').attr('href'); }`

Comment: updated and actually tested...

Comment: @ChadScira that did it! zshooter thanks for all your help both of you!